# Некорректное отображение кода на GitHub

Tags: github, atom, редактор

Загрузил js файл на GitHub. Код пишу в редакторе Atom. По какой-то причине при просмотре на GitHub, весь код съехал на огромные пробелы, при этом в самом редакторе все выглядит нормально. Не понимаю, в чем проблема, из-за использования табуляций, или причина в другом? Как это можно исправить?

Comment: если не сложно, покажи скрин? так будешь проще понять

Comment: Редактор = https://imgur.com/GZxE6p0
GitHub = https://imgur.com/rOieOs5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы всё верно поняли, это происходит из-за использования tab, а именно из-за различных настройках tab в вашем редакторе кода и на github. Лучше всего использовать пробелы, в большенстве случаев таких проблем у вас не будет.

Answer (score 0):

На сайте GitHub величину отступа для табуляции при отображении кода можно задавать аргументом `ts` в URL. Пример: [https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/memory/jedec_ddr.h?**ts=4**#L130](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/memory/jedec_ddr.h?ts=4#L130).

При редактировании файлов на самом сайте имются инструменты для настройки для отступов.

[image: инструменты редактора]